# Replacing in Python

Tags: python

I need to complete a basic task on Python that requires me to convert a standard phone number into an international one.

So for example, if the users phone number was `0123456789`, the program should display, `Your international phone number is +44123456789.`

I don't know how to `replace` the `0` with a `44`. I don't know many techniques on Python so advice on how to is welcomed, thanks.

EDIT:

```
    #Python Number Conversion
def GetInternational(PhoneNumber):
    if num.startswith('0'):
        num = num.replace('0','+44',1)
        return GetInternational

PhoneNumber = input("Enter your phone number: ")
print('Your international number is',GetInternational,'')
```

I'm missing something obvious but not sure what...

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it would be:

```
num.replace('0','+44',1) #Only one, the leftmost zero is replaced
```

Therefore if the number starts with zero we replace only that one,

```
num = "0123456789"

if num.startswith('0'):
    num = num.replace('0','+44',1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Well the simplest way to do it is strip off the first character (the `0`) and then concatenate it with `+"44"`:

```
num = "0123456789"

if num.startswith("0"):
    num = "+44" + num[1:]
```

For clarity I added a `startswith` check to make sure the substitution only happens if the number starts with a zero.